# Organic glitching

Tags: image-processing, glitch

I came across a couple of pictures and was wondering how they achieved such an effect.

[image: processed image of a girl]

[image: processed image of a man]

I believe both pictures were originally still images from a film, then were processed digitally in some way that I am unaware of.

I have tried a few glitching techniques and a few Processing algorithms such as pixel sorting but nothing comes close to the organic feel that these pictures have. Do you have any idea how I can achieve/replicate a similar effect or know of other ways to distort images without them looking too "digital"

Comment: I wonder if it is the halftone moire pattern or the veil-like lines you ar after? It looks like they are photos from a tv-screen.

Comment: @MikaelCarlsson - looks like an answer to me ;) - perhaps you should write it up?

Comment: @GerardFalla - alrighty then! :)

Comment: Please do **not** deface your question. It may help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First Layer

Original Image from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/oYFv-_JKsVk)

Menu Image → Adjustments → Desaturate
[image: Desaturate]

Auto levels:

[image]

## Second Layer

- Levels → Increase highlights and make midtones darker
- Apply a soft Gaussian Blur
- Reduce the opacity to 60%

[image: Blur]

## Third Layer

Adjustment Layer → Photo Filter  → Green, 40%

[image: Photo Filter]

## Fifth Layer

- Make a new layer filled with a pattern: green/red diagonal lines
- Change the blend mode to Darken, 8% opacity

[image: Pattern color]

## Sixth Layer

- Make a new layer filled with a pattern of vertical lines black/white/gray
- Change the blend mode to Multiply, 80% opacity

[image: Sixth Layer]

## Seventh Layer

- Duplicate the last layer and rotate it 90º
- Change the opacity to 20%

[image: Seventh Layer]

## Eigth Layer

Optional: add a noise inverted layer

[image: end]

Answer (score 1):

To get that effect I choose a slight different approach than Danielillo.

[image: Before editing]
I first create a copy of the background layer and use the "Color Halftone" filter on that. After that I use "Gaussian Blur" at 1 pixel to soften the pattern. Set the layer blend to "Lighter color".

[image: After adding Color halftone]

Then make a copy of that layer and use "Liquify" filter and use the twirl tool to move the pattern around a bit here and there. Set the layer blend to "Lighter color" on this layer too.

[image: End result, after using Liquify]

Comment: yours is more akin to a print effect, what OP asks (and on Danielillo answer) is actually a screen / video artifact.